# different Scenes but each of them loads per frame

Tags: unity, unityscript, scene

well i want to have something like restaurant that divided in 3 sections.and the user can switch between these but every Scene loads every frame.for example the character is in the first section and the player goes to second section and touch a customer and the character starts to go to the second section or have a button for kitchen but when the character goes to kitchen the costumers still load.i don't think that `Application.LoadLevel ();` could help.
thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually want scenes, which are more like levels or maps where most of the graphics change, just different areas to move the camera to.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`Application.LoadLevelAdditive`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevelAdditive.html), you can load the scene in parts.

A good idea might be to disable whole sections of the scene that you are not in. For example group the whole scene in one parent gameobject and disable that, or perhaps use a tag for this. You could also use layers, but they're a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use separate levels, you will need to put all of your logic on the same "level" but in different places (within the scene). Then move the camera so that only the things you want to see are visible.